# Why does only 1 bulb stays on?

Tags: lighting, switch

I have a 4 bulb ceiling light which was working perfectly until recently...
When the power is off, the 4th bulb flickers... I removed the 4th bulb, and the 3rd bulb flickers!

So I removed the fuse altogether and left it for another day. I guess this is a light issue rather than a switch issue?

Comment: What type of bulb: incandescent or LED?

Comment: Actually its 3 incandescent and 1 LED (the LED was just a spare bulb i had)- the LED started the flickering, i removed that, then one of the incandescents started flickering.

Comment: What kind of switch? Dimmer? Smart switch? Timer? Lighted switch?

Comment: Just a standard rocker switch

Comment: What fuse did you remove? Does it still flicker now that it's another day?

Comment: Seems to be back to working now! - we did get the switch slightly wet so maybe it's dried out... but I don't understand why it would effect only 1 bulb